# Conditional Validation in Angular 4.4 w/ Material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-forms

I've got a field called `Status` on my template-driven form & the user can set it to either `Draft` or to `Publish`.

The requirement is that when the `status` value is set to `publish`, then almost all of the elements on the form UI must update to show they have become `required` now. And conversely, when it is set back to `draft`, only one of the fields (the title field) needs to be `required`.

What is the trick to pull this off?

I put together the following sample form snippet to discuss the matter.

```
<form class="example-form" novalidate #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">

       <mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup" matInput name="status" [(ngModel)]="status" #field_status="ngModel">
          <mat-button-toggle value="draft">
             DRAFT
          </mat-button-toggle>

          <mat-button-toggle value="publish">
             PUBLISH
          </mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>

    <mat-form-field class="example-medium-width">
        <input matInput name="title" [(ngModel)]="title" placeholder="Title" required  #field_title="ngModel">
        <mat-error *ngIf="field_title.invalid">
            Title is <strong>required</strong>.
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <mat-form-field class="example-medium-width">
        <textarea matInput name="description" [(ngModel)]="description" placeholder="Description" maxlength="50" #field_description="ngModel"></textarea>
        <!-------------------------------------
          how do we make this ALSO required, 
          if the status field is set to publish?
        --------------------------------------->
    </mat-form-field>


    <button [disabled]="!f.form.valid">Submit</button><br>
    <!----------------------------------------------
    the button will not allow the form to submit 
     if title is left blank (when status is draft). 
     BUT, if the status is set to publish, 
     then title alone is not good enough. 
     both Title and Description needs to be filled in! -->


</form>
```

Comment: [required]="status === 'publish'"

Comment: You know, I spent 10 min preparing the question, and you come along out of nowhere and solve it in 5 sec. :) Thank you. --- while we are at it, do you know how to set the status button's default to be the draft one. Tried these but no luck. `<mat-button-toggle checked? selected? default? value="draft">`

Comment: The button is bound, using ngModel, to status. So, in the code of the conmponent, set this.status to 'draft'.